# Using Solve[] to find Eigenstates of a 1D Double Dirac Potential

Tags: equation-solving

I'd like to Solve

$$ k^2 \equiv - \frac{2mE}{\hbar^2} = (- \frac{mA}{\hbar^2} (1+ e^{-2ka}))^2 $$

for E, in terms of m, $\hbar$, A, a.

I tried using the following command:

```
Solve[-((2 m ene)/h^2) == (m^2 A^2)/h^4 (1 + E^(-2 a*Sqrt[-((2 m ene)/h^2)])), ene]
```

Isn't working well for this task. What do you recommend? At first glance it seems it could not be simple to solve "by hand".

***Background***: This problem comes from Solving a 1D Quantum well with 2 Symmetric Dirac' Deltas $\delta_a$ and $\delta_{-a}$, where $A$ is the amplitude.

Comment: Well, not sure yet how to solve this, but your coded expression is missing a square around the 1 plus the exponential term. If you correct that and solve for k, you get a result for k.

Comment: @LouisB actually $E<0$. I forgot to mention that detail, sorry for that. Thanks!

Comment: @CATrevillian I guess solving for $k$ will do. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `Reduce[k^2 == -((2 m*ene)/
   h^2) == (-((m*A)/h^2) (1 + E^(-2 k*a)))^2, ene]`